# Which tag happened after a commit in git?

Tags: git

For a given commit, is it possible to determine the closest tag after the commit? I could not figure out how to do this with git describe or git log?

Example: 
We tag all our releases. I would like to generate release notes which describe which release a commit went into. I can get the most recent tag, but that only shows which release preceded it. I want to know which release came after it

Comment: The git-describe manpage literally states `--contains: Instead of finding the tag that predates the commit, find the tag that comes after the commit, and thus contains it.`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *git describe --contains*  ?

from [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe):

> --contains
>   Instead of finding the tag that predates the commit, find the tag that comes after the commit, and thus contains it. Automatically implies --tags.

Comment: Note that this works differently than `git describe` since it implies `--tags` (matches both annotated and lightweight tags). (`git version 2.40.0`)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want `git describe --contains <commit>`

> --contains
>
> Instead of finding the tag that predates the commit, find the tag that comes after the commit, and thus contains it. Automatically implies --tags.