# Get *next* tag, like git describe but "forwards"

Tags: git, semantic-versioning

With `git describe`, I can get information about the latest tag on which my current commit is based, and how far away from it I am.

I'm looking for a way to, based on the same information, build a semantic version number for a beta-version of the *next* release. In other words, given a tree like

```
A -- B -- C -- D
|              |
v1.2.3         HEAD
```

Now, `git describe` can give me something like `v1.2.3-4-D` - but how do I get to something like `v1.2.4-beta` or `v1.3.0-beta` (depending on which segment I say I want to increment)? Is there some tool built into  git to handle this, or do I have to start with `git describe` and then pass that to something else that can increment for me?

---

The proposed duplicate question does not solve my problem, because it relies on `git describe --contains`, and that only works if the future tag already exists. I'm looking for a way to, given the previous tag, *infer* what the upcoming release version *will be*, by giving only the current repo state and which part (major/minor/patch) should be incremented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which tag happened after a commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857509/which-tag-happened-after-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: @max630: No, that question asks about how to do this _when the next tag exists_, while this question is about inferring _what the next tag will be before it exists_.

Comment: Git does not know when, with what name, on which commit to create a tag.

Comment: Write a script, which finds the last version tag on your branch (for example : by reading it from the output of `git describe --tags`), and builds the next version you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments seem to indicate that this is not possible with plain `git` commands; therefore, I've resorted to use [GitVersion](http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which solves exactly the problem I want to solve (albeit using a small yml file on disk to store data about what version, rather than deriving it from `git describe`).

Comment: That seems like the right kind of answer, but note that this really has nothing to do with *Git*: we'd use exactly the same procedure to determine what to label the next version if we were storing it in Mercurial, or P4, or even no formal version control system at all.

Comment: @torek: Sure. But I couldn't know that when I asked the question, could I? ;) And I might still be proven wrong - if there is a way to build this information from `git` commands, without relying on tools like GitVersion (which does much more than what I need), it could be a better solution than what I have now.